# What is the most direct English equivalent to "халява"?

Tags: перевод

This word, халява, it is interesting.
Google translate translates it as "freebie", but Russian students use it to describe a situation when they didn't study for a test and get an "A" anyway. "Freebie" doesn't really apply here. Google image search turns up a lot of interesting pictures for халява. But finding an English equivalent is proving taxing.
I'm thinking of:

"blind idiot luck" *
gravy train  *
sependipity  *

but I don't think any of those are exact translations.

Comment: [Что такое "халява", и как её перевести?](http://www.bbc.com/russian/blogs/2014/06/140609_blog_strana_russia_martin_khalyava#orb-footer)

Comment: in my dictionary, freebie is translated as `что-либо, полученное бесплатно, задаром, "на халяву"`, and if this is correct, then it applies perfectly to the situation with students, that you described.

Comment: also `халява` means 'a prostitute'

Comment: @user907860 Never heard this. "Шалава" maybe?

Comment: @Matt no, exactly халява. It is not widely used, but such meaning exists and you can hear it from time to time (I mean it exists not only in some dictionary) As a reference, this is what I've found from first several links provided by Google to the request `халява значение проститутка` https://otvet.mail.ru/question/5036187 the first answer has a reference to some dictionary (В.М. Мокиенко и Т.Г. Никитиной (СПб.: Норинт, 2001))  and it clearly states that the word has the meaning of `воровка` (a female thief) and `проститутка`

Comment: Actually, I think 'халява' in the meaning of 'a prostitute' is a part of the criminal slang, and may be they are interchangeable, though I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @user907860 Sure, female thieves worked as prostitutes too. I mean I never heard that word "in common use", though the dictionaries still has it.

Comment: Question was closed here, with suggestion to ask in ELL. But in ELL, how many people understand what халява is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word `халява` is sometimes used when you get something without any kind of work (not only without money). So in this situation student got "A" without work (studying) and called it `халява`.
Easy work itself also can be `халява`. For example, you could say in dialog:

> — Чем сейчас на работе занимаешься?
>   — Да ничем. Сижу за компьютером, смотрю в монитор, изредка нажимаю кнопку, чтобы дверь кому-нибудь открыть...
>   — Вот халява!

As far as I know, there is no full equivalent of word `халява` in English.

Answer (score 1):

> Russian students use it to describe a situation when they didn't study for a test and get an "A" anyway

This meaning is really specific to **student slang**. Especially "the magic spell": *Халява, ловись!*

But colloquially *халява* still has two meanings:

- *a thing* given (or even taken, sometimes ;-) for free (or at very little price), i.e. *freebie*
- *a work* done badly; here *халява* is very close to another nice word *халтура*, though there's a little difference: *халява* is about *lazyness*, while *халтура* is about *negligence*

So *халява* in student slang is something like both at once: no learning (lazy working) and getting good marks ("freebies").

Comment: you are wrong. халтура - is a work done badly, equally due to idleness,  or without one. Халява - is never a work done badly. It is only a result, something acquired without putting too much effort. So if one did some work badly he calls it only `халтура`, but if the customer, for instance, accepted such a work, then one can call all this situation `халява`

Comment: @user907860 Well, at least in my personal opinion _халява_ is both a "free stuff" and any (easy) process of getting it.

Comment: yes, this is correct, but the second item in the list is not correct

Comment: Never heard definition #2. The **undeserved payoff** from a badly done work is, however, perfectly covered under the first definition :)